# Providing several non-textual files to a single map in Hadoop MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm currently writing distributed application which parses Pdf files with the help of Hadoop MapReduce. Input to MapReduce job is thousands of Pdf files (which mostly range from 100KB to ~2MB), and output is a set of parsed text files.

For testing purposes, initially I used `WholeFileInputFormat` provided in Tom White's *Hadoop. The Definitive Guide* book, which provides single file to single map. This worked fine with small number of input files, however, it does not work properly with thousands of files for obvious reasons. Single map for the task which takes around a second to complete is inefficient.

So, what I want to do is to submit several Pdf files into one Map (for example, combining several files into single chunk which has around HDFS block size ~64MB). I found out that `CombineFileInputFormat` is useful for my case. However I cannot come out with idea how to extend that abstract class, so that I can process each file and its filename as a single Key-Value record.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a SequenceFile will suit your needs here: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SequenceFile

Essentially, you put all your PDFs into a sequence file and the mappers will receive as many PDFs as fit into one HDFS block of the sequence file. When you create the sequence file, you'll set the key to be the PDF filename, and the value will be the binary representation of the PDF.

Comment: Even if the pdfs would be sequencefiles, Hadoop would create a mapper for each file using the filesplit.

Comment: If I use 'SequenceFile', I need to convert all my 10,000 pdfs to 'SequenceFile' chunks. That, in turn, again involve submitting each file to each map in this conversion phase, which is not very efficient. Anyway, thanks for your comment.

Comment: Creating the sequence file shouldn't take a very long time, and the efficiency gain comes from using that file more than once. It has been a while since I used them, but if I recall correctly, the sequence file will result in one instance of a Mapper per HDFS chunk on the task trackers, and those instances will invoke the map method once for each record in the local chunk (the inputsplit) of the sequencefile.  The most important overhead to eliminate is the creation of the mapper instance, not multiple invocations of the map method within a Mapper instance.

Comment: Thank you, stinkymatt. I converted all my pdfs into 1 GB chunks of sequence files, and that operation is not expensive. I combined the task of putting all the pdf to SequenceFile and loading them to HDFS by directly writing SequenceFiles into HDFS. Now each Mapper gets 64Mb chunk of sequencefile.

Comment: Putting 1Gb of small Pdf files into sequence file takes around 2 min.

Answer (score 0):

You can create text files with HDFS pathes to your files and use it as an input. It will give Your the mapper reuse for many file, but will cost the data locality. If your data is relatively small, high replication factor (close to number of data nodes) will solve the problem.

Comment: In this case, do I need to implement custom RecordReader and InputFormat or is there some implementation ready for use?