# how to force hadoop to process more data per map

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a job which is going very slowly because I think hadoop is creating too many map tasks for the size of the data. I read on some websites that its efficient for fewer maps to process bigger chunks of data -- is there any way to force this? Thanks

Comment: by the way, the job seems to be making ~2400 maps for ~90gb of data

Comment: Why do you suspect the number of mappers as the cause of the delay?  Have you watched the job execute?  Have you used vaidya or any other tool to analyze the skew of your data, or the size of your intermediate outputs?  In my experience the bottleneck almost always comes down to I/O or data skew.  Number of mappers is just not a factor (2400 seems about right for the dataset size you have).

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities:

1. increase the block size of your 90gb data, setting this to 128m or larger will make your map tasks "work more"
2. use the [`CombineFileInputFormat`](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/CombineFileInputFormat.html) and batch your blocks together to the size you think it is appropriate.

The first solution requires you to rewrite the data to change the block size, the second solution can be embedded in your job.

Comment: Depending on your input format, size of your files (they must be larger than a single block) and whether your input files are splittable, you have a 3rd option which is to amend the `mapred.min.split.size` and `mapred.max.split.size` configuration properties - this will most probably reduce data locality however so could slow your job down

Answer (score 1):

Many maps indeed can have serious performance impact since overhead of map task starting is from 1 to 3 seconds, depending on your settings and hardware. 
The main setting here is JVM reuse (mapred.job.reuse.jvm.num.tasks). Set it to -1 and you will probabbly got serious performance boost. 
The usual root cause of this problem is a lot of small files. It is discussed here:
[Processing large set of small files with Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930955/processing-large-set-of-small-files-with-hadoop)
The solutions are around orgenizing them together. 
If your files are indeed big, but splittable - you can increase block side, thus reducing number of split and thereof - number of maps

Answer (score 0):

Increase the split size or use CombineFileInputFormat for packing multiple files in a single split thus reducing the number of map tasks required to process the data.