# How to get pixel rgb value in hadoop?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, hadoop, hdfs

I have millions of images stored in hdfs of hadoop. I want to build a index of these images. How to get pixel rgb values of these images? I am new in hadoop, the image format in hadoop is different from the original image binary format. Another problem is should I use the sequencefile in hadoop to pack the enormous images to a big file for efficiency? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I could answer the problem partially.

> Another problem is should I use the sequencefile in hadoop to pack the enormous images to a big file for efficiency?

Depends on the size of the individual files. If the individual files are really big, then consolidating them might not really help and the other way also.

Check this [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930955/processing-large-set-of-small-files-with-hadoop) on SO for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the additional storage and efficiency is important to you I would definitely go with a SequenceFile. Hadoop will handle splitting the file up for you. We ran into a case where we were extracting data from imagery file similar to what you are doing. In our case we were extracting metadata for ingestion in a discovery system so that our imagery files could be searched outside of the cluster. In this case because efficiency was not a big deal for us we just process the files individually making sure to make them not splittable. This way the other system can reach back over http to grab the source files.