# How to store lots of small HTML files in Google Cloud Storage to optimize Dataproc?

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm interested in trying out Google Cloud Dataproc on an HTML parsing task. We currently have lots (200M+) of small HTML files on google storage. We'd like the ability to pull all these files into Hadoop (either MapReduce or Spark) for processing.

However, my understanding is that Dataproc will perform poorly when listing and reading lots of small files, and that this is generally true of Hadoop as well. So my question is, how should I bundle lots of small files into larger files, that can be listed and read efficiently?

I've considered standard stuff like TAR/ZIP, but my understanding is that these are not splittable, and therefore concurrency is limited.

Is there another format that's recommended for something like this? I've considered using avro, and just storing the HTMLs as a byte field inside an avro record, but I don't think avro is really intended for this kind use-case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Hadoop SequenceFile](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SequenceFile) to solve this issue as it suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5133949/3227693).